# Is "The lake is going to be busy all weekends" correct

Tags: grammar

Title sums it up, it sounds weird, but is it worded correctly? As well as grammatically correct?

Comment: It should be "weekend," not "weekends." Rest is fine.

Comment: If you mean that it will be busy every weekend of the summer, it's technically correct (though not particularly idiomatic).  If you mean that it will be busy both Saturday and Sunday of the next coming weekend, then you shouldn't use the plural.

Answer (score 1):

Except, as noted elsewhere, the plural "weekends", it sounds perfectly correct and perfectly idiomatic to me.

Did you mean “The lake is going to be busy all weekend, every weekend”?